# Kivy's 3D rendering (monkey rotation) apk crashes on start

Tags: python, kivy, apk

Versions:

- Python: python3
- OS: Android
- Kivy: v1.11.1
- Kivy installation method: buildozer

I took Kivy's example 3D Rendering (rotation monkey head) app,
on Linux(Ubuntu) and Windows 7 application works fine, (run it from python console), but when I compile in apk and try to run on Android phone its crashes! Another app without shader(OpenGL2) works on android after compilation in apk, but this one don't( Maybe the problem in shader?
How to configurate it? In buildozer.spec I add glsl, and obj extensions

This what adb logcat shows:

```
12-02 09:24:51.834  1907  1907 D PhoneStatusBar/NavigationBarView: setDisabledFlags back:false home:false recent:false
12-02 09:24:51.835  1907  1907 D PhoneStatusBar/NavigationBarView: setDisabledFlags back:false home:false recent:false
12-02 09:24:51.875  1907  1907 D EventBus: [1907, u0] send(AppTransitionFinishedEvent)
12-02 09:24:51.875  1907  1907 D EventBus: [1907, u0]  -> ForcedResizableInfoActivityController [0x74afc88, P1] onBusEvent(AppTransitionFinishedEvent)

12-02 09:24:51.875  1907  1907 D EventBus: [1907, u0] onBusEvent(AppTransitionFinishedEvent) duration: 22 microseconds, avg: 404
12-02 09:24:51.875  1907  1907 D EventBus: [1907, u0] unregister()
12-02 09:24:51.878  1907  1907 D StatusBar: disable<e i a s b h r c s q >
12-02 09:24:51.879  1907  1907 D PhoneStatusBar/NavigationBarView: setDisabledFlags back:false home:false recent:false
12-02 09:24:51.879  1907  1907 D PhoneStatusBar/NavigationBarView: setDisabledFlags back:false home:false recent:false
12-02 09:24:51.888  1907  2223 D NetworkTypeUtils: getDataNetTypeFromServiceState:srcDataNetType = 13, destDataNetType 13
12-02 09:24:51.889  1907  2223 D MobileSignalController: updateDataType mSelectedDataTypeIcon[0]=2131231623, mSelectedDataActivityIndex=6
12-02 09:24:51.890  1907  2223 D TelephonyIcons: getSignalStrengthIcon: slot=0, inetCondition=1, level=5, roaming=false
12-02 09:24:51.890  1907  2223 D TelephonyIcons: getDataActivity, slot=0, activity=4
12-02 09:24:51.891  1907  2223 D TelephonyIcons: null signal icon name: drawable/stat_sys_signal_null
12-02 09:24:51.891  1907  2223 D TelephonyIcons: getDataTypeIcon sub=0
12-02 09:24:51.894  1907  2223 D NetworkTypeUtils: getDataNetTypeFromServiceState:srcDataNetType = 13, destDataNetType 13
12-02 09:24:51.895  1907  2223 D MobileSignalController: updateDataType mSelectedDataTypeIcon[0]=2131231623, mSelectedDataActivityIndex=6
12-02 09:24:51.895  1907  2223 D TelephonyIcons: getSignalStrengthIcon: slot=0, inetCondition=1, level=5, roaming=false
12-02 09:24:51.895  1907  2223 D TelephonyIcons: getDataActivity, slot=0, activity=4
12-02 09:24:51.897  1907  2223 D TelephonyIcons: null signal icon name: drawable/stat_sys_signal_null
12-02 09:24:51.897  1907  2223 D TelephonyIcons: getDataTypeIcon sub=0
12-02 09:24:51.902  1907  1907 W PhoneStatusBar/NavigationBarView: *** Invalid layout in navigation bar (sizeChanged this=130x1080 cur=1080x130)
12-02 09:24:51.935  7274  7274 V PythonActivity: PythonActivity onCreate running
12-02 09:24:51.935  7274  7274 V PythonActivity: About to do super onCreate
12-02 09:24:51.935  7274  7274 V SDL     : Device: vince
12-02 09:24:51.936  7274  7274 V SDL     : Model: Redmi 5 Plus
12-02 09:24:51.936  7274  7274 V SDL     : onCreate()
12-02 09:24:51.939  7274  7274 V PythonActivity: Did super onCreate
12-02 09:24:51.939  7274  7274 V SDL     : getting identifier
12-02 09:24:51.939  7274  7274 V SDL     : kind is drawable and name presplash
12-02 09:24:51.940  7274  7274 V SDL     : result is 2130771970
12-02 09:24:51.963  7274  7274 V SDL     : asked to get string presplash_color
12-02 09:24:51.963  7274  7274 V SDL     : getting identifier
12-02 09:24:51.963  7274  7274 V SDL     : kind is string and name presplash_color
12-02 09:24:51.963  7274  7274 V SDL     : result is 2130968577
12-02 09:24:51.967  7274  7274 D AccessibilityManager: AccessibilityManager status: mPackageName = org.test.myapp, mOptimizeEnabled = false, mIsEnable
d = false, mIsUiAutomationEnabled = false, mIsInterestedPackage =false
12-02 09:24:51.986  7274  7302 V PythonActivity: Ready to unpack
12-02 09:24:51.986  7274  7302 V PythonActivity: UNPACKING!!! private app
12-02 09:24:51.986  7274  7302 V SDL     : asked to get string private_version
12-02 09:24:51.986  7274  7302 V SDL     : getting identifier
12-02 09:24:51.986  7274  7302 V SDL     : kind is string and name private_version
12-02 09:24:51.986  7274  7302 V SDL     : result is 2130968578
12-02 09:24:51.987  7274  7302 V PythonActivity: Data version is 1575268688.928001
12-02 09:24:51.992  7274  7274 V PythonActivity: onResume()
12-02 09:24:51.992  7274  7274 V SDL     : onResume()
12-02 09:24:52.006  7274  7303 D OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline
12-02 09:24:52.015  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libsqlite3\.so against libssl1.1.so
12-02 09:24:52.016  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libsqlite3\.so against libSDL2_mixer.so
12-02 09:24:52.016  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libsqlite3\.so against libSDL2_ttf.so
12-02 09:24:52.016  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libsqlite3\.so against libmain.so
12-02 09:24:52.016  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libsqlite3\.so against libSDL2.so
12-02 09:24:52.016  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libsqlite3\.so against libhidapi.so
12-02 09:24:52.017  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libsqlite3\.so against libffi.so
12-02 09:24:52.017  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libsqlite3\.so against libsqlite3.so
12-02 09:24:52.017  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Pattern libsqlite3\.so matched file libsqlite3.so
12-02 09:24:52.017  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libsqlite3\.so against libcrypto1.1.so
12-02 09:24:52.018  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libsqlite3\.so against libSDL2_image.so
12-02 09:24:52.018  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libsqlite3\.so against libpython3.7m.so
12-02 09:24:52.019  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libffi\.so against libssl1.1.so
12-02 09:24:52.019  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libffi\.so against libSDL2_mixer.so
12-02 09:24:52.020  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libffi\.so against libSDL2_ttf.so
12-02 09:24:52.020  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libffi\.so against libmain.so
12-02 09:24:52.020  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libffi\.so against libSDL2.so
12-02 09:24:52.020  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libffi\.so against libhidapi.so
12-02 09:24:52.020  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libffi\.so against libffi.so
12-02 09:24:52.020  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Pattern libffi\.so matched file libffi.so
12-02 09:24:52.021  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libffi\.so against libsqlite3.so
12-02 09:24:52.021  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libffi\.so against libcrypto1.1.so
12-02 09:24:52.021  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libffi\.so against libSDL2_image.so
12-02 09:24:52.021  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libffi\.so against libpython3.7m.so
12-02 09:24:52.022  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libpng16\.so against libssl1.1.so
12-02 09:24:52.022  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libpng16\.so against libSDL2_mixer.so
12-02 09:24:52.022  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libpng16\.so against libSDL2_ttf.so
12-02 09:24:52.023  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libpng16\.so against libmain.so
12-02 09:24:52.023  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libpng16\.so against libSDL2.so
12-02 09:24:52.023  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libpng16\.so against libhidapi.so
12-02 09:24:52.023  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libpng16\.so against libffi.so
12-02 09:24:52.023  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libpng16\.so against libsqlite3.so
12-02 09:24:52.023  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libpng16\.so against libcrypto1.1.so
12-02 09:24:52.024  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libpng16\.so against libSDL2_image.so
12-02 09:24:52.024  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libpng16\.so against libpython3.7m.so
12-02 09:24:52.025  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libssl.*\.so against libssl1.1.so
12-02 09:24:52.025  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Pattern libssl.*\.so matched file libssl1.1.so
12-02 09:24:52.025  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libssl.*\.so against libSDL2_mixer.so
12-02 09:24:52.025  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libssl.*\.so against libSDL2_ttf.so
12-02 09:24:52.025  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libssl.*\.so against libmain.so
12-02 09:24:52.026  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libssl.*\.so against libSDL2.so
12-02 09:24:52.026  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libssl.*\.so against libhidapi.so
12-02 09:24:52.026  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libssl.*\.so against libffi.so
12-02 09:24:52.026  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libssl.*\.so against libsqlite3.so
12-02 09:24:52.026  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libssl.*\.so against libcrypto1.1.so
12-02 09:24:52.026  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libssl.*\.so against libSDL2_image.so
12-02 09:24:52.027  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libssl.*\.so against libpython3.7m.so
12-02 09:24:52.027  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libcrypto.*\.so against libssl1.1.so
12-02 09:24:52.028  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libcrypto.*\.so against libSDL2_mixer.so
12-02 09:24:52.028  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libcrypto.*\.so against libSDL2_ttf.so
12-02 09:24:52.028  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libcrypto.*\.so against libmain.so
12-02 09:24:52.028  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libcrypto.*\.so against libSDL2.so
12-02 09:24:52.028  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libcrypto.*\.so against libhidapi.so
12-02 09:24:52.028  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libcrypto.*\.so against libffi.so
12-02 09:24:52.029  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libcrypto.*\.so against libsqlite3.so
12-02 09:24:52.029  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libcrypto.*\.so against libcrypto1.1.so
12-02 09:24:52.029  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Pattern libcrypto.*\.so matched file libcrypto1.1.so
12-02 09:24:52.029  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libcrypto.*\.so against libSDL2_image.so
12-02 09:24:52.029  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Checking pattern libcrypto.*\.so against libpython3.7m.so
12-02 09:24:52.030  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Loading library: sqlite3
12-02 09:24:52.033  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Loading library: ffi
12-02 09:24:52.035  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Loading library: SDL2
12-02 09:24:52.039  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Loading library: SDL2_image
12-02 09:24:52.041  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Loading library: SDL2_mixer
12-02 09:24:52.043  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Loading library: SDL2_ttf
12-02 09:24:52.045  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Loading library: ssl1.1
12-02 09:24:52.048  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Loading library: crypto1.1
12-02 09:24:52.050  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Loading library: python2.7
12-02 09:24:52.054  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Library loading error: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/org.test.myapp-LhVj
fU6-HUnJth0Rf5IwXg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/org.test.myapp-LhVjfU6-HUnJth0Rf5IwXg==/lib/arm, /data/app/org.test.myapp-LhVjfU6-
HUnJth0Rf5IwXg==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]] couldn't find "libpython2.7.so"
12-02 09:24:52.054  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Loading library: python3.5m
12-02 09:24:52.055  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Library loading error: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/org.test.myapp-LhVj
fU6-HUnJth0Rf5IwXg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/org.test.myapp-LhVjfU6-HUnJth0Rf5IwXg==/lib/arm, /data/app/org.test.myapp-LhVjfU6-
HUnJth0Rf5IwXg==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]] couldn't find "libpython3.5m.so"
12-02 09:24:52.055  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Loading library: python3.6m
12-02 09:24:52.056  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Library loading error: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/org.test.myapp-LhVj
fU6-HUnJth0Rf5IwXg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/org.test.myapp-LhVjfU6-HUnJth0Rf5IwXg==/lib/arm, /data/app/org.test.myapp-LhVjfU6-
HUnJth0Rf5IwXg==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]] couldn't find "libpython3.6m.so"
12-02 09:24:52.057  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Loading library: python3.7m
12-02 09:24:52.062  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Loading library: main
12-02 09:24:52.064  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Failed to load _io.so or unicodedata.so...but that's okay.
12-02 09:24:52.065  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Unsatisfied linker when loading ctypes
12-02 09:24:52.065  7274  7274 V pythonutil: Loaded everything!
12-02 09:24:52.066  7274  7274 V SDL     : nativeSetupJNI()
12-02 09:24:52.066  7274  7274 V SDL     : AUDIO nativeSetupJNI()
12-02 09:24:52.066  7274  7274 V SDL     : CONTROLLER nativeSetupJNI()
12-02 09:24:52.076  7274  7274 D hidapi  : Initializing Bluetooth
12-02 09:24:52.076  7274  7274 D hidapi  : Couldn't initialize Bluetooth, missing android.permission.BLUETOOTH
12-02 09:24:52.093  7274  7274 V PythonActivity: Setting env vars for start.c and Python to use
12-02 09:24:52.093  7274  7274 V PythonActivity: Access to our meta-data...
12-02 09:24:52.095  7274  7274 I PythonActivity: Surface will NOT be transparent
12-02 09:24:52.095  7274  7274 V PythonActivity: onResume()
12-02 09:24:52.095  7274  7274 V SDL     : onResume()
12-02 09:24:52.114  7274  7303 I Adreno  : QUALCOMM build                   : 8e3df98, Ie4790512f3
12-02 09:24:52.114  7274  7303 I Adreno  : Build Date                       : 04/11/18
12-02 09:24:52.114  7274  7303 I Adreno  : OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: EV031.22.00.01
12-02 09:24:52.114  7274  7303 I Adreno  : Local Branch                     :
12-02 09:24:52.114  7274  7303 I Adreno  : Remote Branch                    : quic/gfx-adreno.lnx.1.0.r36-rel
12-02 09:24:52.114  7274  7303 I Adreno  : Remote Branch                    : NONE
12-02 09:24:52.114  7274  7303 I Adreno  : Reconstruct Branch               : NOTHING
12-02 09:24:52.115  7274  7303 D vndksupport: Loading /vendor/lib/hw/gralloc.msm8953.so from current namespace instead of sphal namespace.
12-02 09:24:52.120  7274  7303 I Adreno  : PFP: 0x005ff087, ME: 0x005ff063
12-02 09:24:52.124  7274  7303 I zygote  : android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
12-02 09:24:52.125  7274  7303 I OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
12-02 09:24:52.125  7274  7303 D OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 2
12-02 09:24:52.129  7274  7274 V SDL     : surfaceCreated()
12-02 09:24:52.130  7274  7274 V SDL     : surfaceChanged()
12-02 09:24:52.130  7274  7274 V SDL     : pixel format RGB_565
12-02 09:24:52.131  7274  7274 V SDL     : Window size: 2030x1014
12-02 09:24:52.131  7274  7274 V SDL     : Device size: 2160x1080
12-02 09:24:52.137  7274  7274 V SDL     : nativeResume()
12-02 09:24:52.137  7274  7306 V SDL     : Running main function SDL_main from library /data/app/org.test.myapp-LhVjfU6-HUnJth0Rf5IwXg==/lib/arm/libma
in.so
12-02 09:24:52.137  7274  7306 V PythonActivity: appConfirmedActive() -> preparing loading screen removal
12-02 09:24:52.137  7274  7306 V SDL     : nativeRunMain()
12-02 09:24:52.138  7274  7306 I python  : Initializing Python for Android
12-02 09:24:52.138  7274  7306 I python  : Setting additional env vars from p4a_env_vars.txt
12-02 09:24:52.138  7274  7306 I python  : Changing directory to the one provided by ANDROID_ARGUMENT
12-02 09:24:52.138  7274  7306 I python  : /data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app
12-02 09:24:52.138  7274  7306 I python  : Preparing to initialize python
12-02 09:24:52.139  7274  7306 I python  : _python_bundle dir exists
12-02 09:24:52.139  7274  7306 I python  : calculated paths to be...
12-02 09:24:52.139  7274  7306 I python  : /data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app/_python_bundle/stdlib.zip:/data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app/_pyth
on_bundle/modules
12-02 09:24:52.139  7274  7306 I python  : set wchar paths...
12-02 09:24:52.156  7274  7303 D vndksupport: Loading /vendor/lib/hw/android.hardware.graphics.mapper@2.0-impl.so from current namespace instead of sp
hal namespace.
12-02 09:24:52.157  7274  7303 D vndksupport: Loading /vendor/lib/hw/gralloc.msm8953.so from current namespace instead of sphal namespace.
12-02 09:24:52.159  7274  7303 E libEGL  : error opening cache file /data/user_de/0/org.test.myapp/code_cache/com.android.opengl.shaders_cache: Permis
sion denied (13)
12-02 09:24:52.194  7274  7306 I python  : Initialized python
12-02 09:24:52.194  7274  7306 I python  : AND: Init threads
12-02 09:24:52.196  7274  7306 I python  : testing python print redirection
12-02 09:24:52.197  7274  7306 I python  : Android path ['.', '/data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app/_python_bundle/stdlib.zip', '/data/user/0/org.tes
t.myapp/files/app/_python_bundle/modules', '/data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages']
12-02 09:24:52.198  7274  7306 I python  : os.environ is environ({'PATH': '/sbin:/system/sbin:/system/bin:/system/xbin:/vendor/bin:/vendor/xbin', 'DOW
NLOAD_CACHE': '/data/cache', 'ANDROID_BOOTLOGO': '1', 'ANDROID_ROOT': '/system', 'ANDROID_ASSETS': '/system/app', 'ANDROID_DATA': '/data', 'ANDROID_ST
ORAGE': '/storage', 'EXTERNAL_STORAGE': '/sdcard', 'ASEC_MOUNTPOINT': '/mnt/asec', 'BOOTCLASSPATH': '/system/framework/com.qualcomm.qti.camera.jar:/sy
stem/framework/QPerformance.jar:/system/framework/core-oj.jar:/system/framework/core-libart.jar:/system/framework/conscrypt.jar:/system/framework/okht
tp.jar:/system/framework/bouncycastle.jar:/system/framework/apache-xml.jar:/system/framework/legacy-test.jar:/system/framework/ext.jar:/system/framewo
rk/framework.jar:/system/framework/telephony-common.jar:/system/framework/voip-common.jar:/system/framework/ims-common.jar:/system/framework/org.apach
e.http.legacy.boot.jar:/system/framework/android.hidl.base-V1.0-java.jar:/system/framework/android.hidl.manager-V1.0-java.jar:/system/framework/tcmifa
ce.jar:/system/framework/WfdCommon.jar:/system/framework/oem-services.jar:/system/framework/qcom.fmradio.jar:/system/framework/telephony-ext.jar:/syst
em/app/miui/miui.apk:/system/app/miuisystem/miuisystem.apk', 'SYSTEMSERVERCLASSPATH': '/system/framework/services.jar:/system/framework/ethernet-servi
ce.jar:/system/framework/wifi-service.jar:/system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar', 'ANDROID_SOCKET_zygote_secondary': '10', 'ANDROID_ENTR
YPOINT': 'main.pyc', 'ANDROID_ARGUMENT': '/data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app', 'ANDROID_APP_PATH': '/data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app', 'ANDROI
D_PRIVATE': '/data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files', 'ANDROID_UNPACK': '/data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app', 'PYTHONHOME': '/data/user/0/org.test.myapp
/files/app', 'PYTHONPATH': '/data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app:/data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app/lib', 'PYTHONOPTIMIZE': '2', 'P4A_BOOTSTRAP':
'SDL2', 'PYTHON_NAME': 'python', 'P4A_IS_WINDOWED': 'True', 'P4A_ORIENTATION': 'landscape', 'P4A_NUMERIC_VERSION': 'None', 'P4A_MINSDK': '21', 'LC_CTY
PE': 'C.UTF-8'})
12-02 09:24:52.198  7274  7306 I python  : Android kivy bootstrap done. __name__ is __main__
12-02 09:24:52.198  7274  7306 I python  : AND: Ran string
12-02 09:24:52.198  7274  7306 I python  : Run user program, change dir and execute entrypoint
12-02 09:24:52.245  7274  7274 V SDL     : onWindowFocusChanged(): true
12-02 09:24:52.250  1589  1652 I ActivityManager: Displayed org.test.myapp/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity: +690ms
12-02 09:24:52.250  1589  1652 E ANDR-PERF-JNI: com_qualcomm_qtiperformance_native_perf_io_prefetch_start
12-02 09:24:52.250  3699  4041 D PowerKeeper.Event: notifyActivityLaunchTime: org.test.myapp/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity totalTime: 690
12-02 09:24:52.275  1589  2154 D ActivityTrigger: ActivityTrigger activityStopTrigger
12-02 09:24:52.281  1589  2154 W System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /acct/uid_99108/pid_32148/cgroup.procs (No such file or directory)
12-02 09:24:52.281  1589  2154 W System.err:    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
12-02 09:24:52.281  1589  2154 W System.err:    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:200)
12-02 09:24:52.281  1589  2154 W System.err:    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:150)
12-02 09:24:52.281  1589  2154 W System.err:    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:103)
12-02 09:24:52.281  1589  2154 W System.err:    at com.miui.server.PerfShielderService.setForkedProcessGroup(PerfShielderService.java:217)
12-02 09:24:52.281  1589  2154 W System.err:    at com.android.server.am.ExtraActivityManagerService.setForkedProcessGroup(ExtraActivityManagerService
.java:1267)
12-02 09:24:52.281  1589  2154 W System.err:    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerServiceInjector.setForkedProcessGroup(ActivityManagerServiceIn
jector.java:1012)
12-02 09:24:52.281  1589  2154 W System.err:    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.applyOomAdjLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:22812)
12-02 09:24:52.281  1589  2154 W System.err:    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.updateOomAdjLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:23433)
12-02 09:24:52.281  1589  2154 W System.err:    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.trimApplications(ActivityManagerService.java:24178)
12-02 09:24:52.281  1589  2154 W System.err:    at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.activityIdleInternalLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.ja
va:2068)
12-02 09:24:52.281  1589  2154 W System.err:    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.activityIdle(ActivityManagerService.java:7540)
12-02 09:24:52.281  1589  2154 W System.err:    at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:310)
12-02 09:24:52.281  1589  2154 W System.err:    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3020)
12-02 09:24:52.281  1589  2154 W System.err:    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:702)
12-02 09:24:52.409  7274  7306 I python  : [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app/.kivy/logs/kivy_19-12-02_3.txt

12-02 09:24:52.410  7274  7306 I python  : [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
12-02 09:24:52.410  7274  7306 I python  : [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/k
ivy/__init__.pyc"
12-02 09:24:52.410  7274  7306 I python  : [INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.1 (default, Nov 28 2019, 23:47:24)
12-02 09:24:52.410  7274  7306 I python  : [Clang 6.0.2 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/clang 183abd29fc496f55
12-02 09:24:52.410  7274  7306 I python  : [INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "android_python"
12-02 09:24:52.411  7274  7306 I python  : [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge log fired. Analysing...
12-02 09:24:52.411  7274  7306 I python  : [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge finished!
12-02 09:24:52.536  1907  1907 D KeyguardUpdateMonitor: received broadcast android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
12-02 09:24:52.536  1907  1907 D KeyguardUpdateMonitor: handleBatteryUpdate
12-02 09:24:52.536  2905  2905 I BatteryInfoReceiver: ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED
12-02 09:24:52.536  3699  4127 D PowerCheckerService: onBatteryChanged, mBatteryLevel = 77, status = 3, level = 77, plug = 0
12-02 09:24:53.415  7274  7306 I python  : [INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
12-02 09:24:53.537  1907  1907 D KeyguardUpdateMonitor: received broadcast android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
12-02 09:24:53.537  2905  2905 I BatteryInfoReceiver: ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED
12-02 09:24:53.537  1907  1907 D KeyguardUpdateMonitor: handleBatteryUpdate
12-02 09:24:53.538  3699  4127 D PowerCheckerService: onBatteryChanged, mBatteryLevel = 77, status = 3, level = 77, plug = 0
12-02 09:24:53.973  7274  7306 I python  : [INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_gif (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
12-02 09:24:54.067  7274  7306 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
12-02 09:24:54.098  7274  7306 E libEGL  : validate_display:92 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
12-02 09:24:54.099  7274  7306 V SDL     : setOrientation() orientation=-1 width=800 height=600 resizable=true hint=
12-02 09:24:54.106  7274  7306 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL ES 2" graphics system
12-02 09:24:54.108  7274  7306 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <sdl2>
12-02 09:24:54.109  7274  7306 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'OpenGL ES 3.2 V@269.0 (GIT@8e3df98, Ie4790512f3) (Date:04/11/18)
'>
12-02 09:24:54.109  7274  7306 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Qualcomm'>
12-02 09:24:54.110  7274  7306 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Adreno (TM) 506'>
12-02 09:24:54.110  7274  7306 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 3, 2
12-02 09:24:54.110  7274  7306 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
12-02 09:24:54.111  7274  7306 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
12-02 09:24:54.166  7274  7306 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
12-02 09:24:54.168  7274  7306 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
12-02 09:24:54.174  7274  7306 I python  : [INFO   ] [Shader      ] Read </data/data/org.test.myapp/files/app/simple.glsl>
12-02 09:24:54.195  7274  7306 I python  : [WARNING] [Base        ] Unknown <android> provider
12-02 09:24:54.195  7274  7306 I python  : [INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
12-02 09:24:54.204  7274  7306 F libc    : Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x34 in tid 7306 (SDLThread), pid 7274 (org.test.myapp)
12-02 09:24:54.237  7319  7319 W crash_dump32: type=1400 audit(0.0:5833): avc: denied { search } for name="org.test.myapp" dev="dm-1" ino=415598 scont
ext=u:r:crash_dump:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
12-02 09:24:54.247  7319  7319 I chatty  : uid=10140(org.test.myapp) crash_dump32 identical 36 lines
12-02 09:24:54.247  7319  7319 W crash_dump32: type=1400 audit(0.0:5870): avc: denied { search } for name="org.test.myapp" dev="dm-1" ino=415598 scont
ext=u:r:crash_dump:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
12-02 09:24:54.271  7319  7319 I crash_dump32: obtaining output fd from tombstoned, type: kDebuggerdTombstone
12-02 09:24:54.272   927   927 I /system/bin/tombstoned: received crash request for pid 7274
12-02 09:24:54.273  7319  7319 I crash_dump32: performing dump of process 7274 (target tid = 7306)
12-02 09:24:54.273  7319  7319 F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
12-02 09:24:54.273  7319  7319 F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'xiaomi/vince/vince:8.1.0/OPM1.171019.019/V10.0.4.0.OEGMIFH:user/release-keys'
12-02 09:24:54.273  7319  7319 F DEBUG   : Revision: '0'
12-02 09:24:54.273  7319  7319 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'arm'
12-02 09:24:54.273  7319  7319 F DEBUG   : pid: 7274, tid: 7306, name: SDLThread  >>> org.test.myapp <<<
12-02 09:24:54.273  7319  7319 F DEBUG   : signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x34
12-02 09:24:54.273  7319  7319 F DEBUG   : Cause: null pointer dereference
12-02 09:24:54.273  7319  7319 F DEBUG   :     r0 00000001  r1 00000034  r2 d28d7600  r3 00000001
12-02 09:24:54.273  7319  7319 F DEBUG   :     r4 d2758300  r5 00000000  r6 00000000  r7 d28d7600
12-02 09:24:54.274  7319  7319 F DEBUG   :     r8 d28d7654  r9 00008be7  sl 0000002c  fp d28d7654
12-02 09:24:54.274  7319  7319 F DEBUG   :     ip df979065  sp d2a7dd70  lr dfc0cf4b  pc dfc0d200  cpsr 00010030
12-02 09:24:54.300  7319  7319 F DEBUG   :
12-02 09:24:54.300  7319  7319 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
12-02 09:24:54.300  7319  7319 F DEBUG   :     #00 pc 00392200  /system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (EsxContext::DrawParamValidate(unsigned int
, int, int, int, int)+831)
12-02 09:24:54.300  7319  7319 F DEBUG   :     #01 pc 000fe0b9  /system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (EsxGlApiParamValidate::GlDrawElements(EsxD
ispatch*, unsigned int, int, unsigned int, void const*)+84)
12-02 09:24:54.300  7319  7319 F DEBUG   :     #02 pc 0009e401  /system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (glDrawElements+40)
12-02 09:24:54.300  7319  7319 F DEBUG   :     #03 pc 000081ff  /data/data/org.test.myapp/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/graphics/vbo.so
12-02 09:24:54.532  1907  1907 D KeyguardUpdateMonitor: received broadcast android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
12-02 09:24:54.533  1907  1907 D KeyguardUpdateMonitor: handleBatteryUpdate
12-02 09:24:54.533  2905  2905 I BatteryInfoReceiver: ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED
12-02 09:24:54.534  3699  4127 D PowerCheckerService: onBatteryChanged, mBatteryLevel = 77, status = 3, level = 77, plug = 0
12-02 09:24:54.596  1589  1652 I zygote64: Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 127196(8MB) AllocSpace objects, 142(3MB) LOS objects, 42% free, 26MB/4
5MB, paused 190us total 338.186ms`
```

Crash starts from :

```
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x34 in tid 32411 (SDLThread), pid 32376 (org.test.myapp)
```

Maybe someone knows how make deeper analysis, may be there is a way to find program string on which the crash happens?
Forgot to say - this app from Kivy's example 3D Rendering (rotation monkey head)

Comment: eyllanesc, thanks!

Comment: It looks like the backtrace in your posted DEBUG output was just getting into your app at the end of your posted logcat. Are there additional lines in that backtrace?

Comment: You mean addition lines - as I started my app on android?

Comment: I add full log! Somehing is wrong in it?

Comment: Try to launch on Galaxy I9300 works as a charm! Old phone but this kivy works, and on xiaomi redmi 5plus not((

Comment: Founded , that must develop your app in old good java and not stand out with kivy or someone else((